# create outbound message in veeva to a mobile number

Tags: workflow, workflowoutboundmessage

Can someone help me here? I have a requirement to send message notification in mobile number of the User when he/she is inactivated in the system.

```
IF(AND(ISCHANGED(ISACTIVE),NOT(ISNEW())),true,false)
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my formula? Why getting error that `ISCHANGED` can not be used like this?

Comment: IF(AND(ISCHANGED(ISACTIVE),NOT(ISNEW())),true,false)                 Can someone tell me what is wrong in my formula?Why getting error that ISCHANGED can not be used like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saikat

if you change your workflow rule evaluation criteria to **"created, and every time it’s edited"** then your formula will work.

```
IF(
AND(ISCHANGED(ISACTIVE),NOT(ISNEW())),
true,
false
)
```